# chrome.extension.sendRequest() asynchronous problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

I am building a Chrome extension which involves changing the default css of a site, the code skeleton is as follow

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    options: "foo"
}, function(response) {
    if(response=='on'){ 
 var d = document.documentElement;
  var css_chunk = document.createElement("style");
  css_chunk.type = "text/css";
  css_chunk.innerText = "img{ visibility:hidden !important; display:none !important; } ";
  d.insertBefore(css_chunk, null);          
    }
});
```

I found that it's more a like an AJAX call and therefore the css does not alway change before the original website is loaded. The problem is that sometime it "winks" for a very short time before the images disappear. Is there any option to make this call synchronous?

I tied to add sleep(n) outside after the call and it works. However this function is optional for user, i.e. if function is off, the page sleep(n) as well which is not so reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)?
Either that, or write a Greasemonkey script, and save yourself the trouble of writing a full extension.

Comment: In fact the extension is massive and it's one of the functions. We have to build one for our own and even Firefox version in the coming future.